# binding: The edit bindings button (...) is not visible in azure devops

Tags: azure, .net-core, iis, azure-devops

I'm trying to add https binding to IIS in azure devops Cd pipeline.

But it seems I'm not able to see the [..] option to add custom bindings.

[image: Image for reference]

So I'm seeking help to enable option to add custom bindings.

Comment: What is the role of your Azure Account?

Comment: current  role is administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Created `Manage IISWebsite` task in my release pipeline and able to see the `Edit` option for `Add Bindings`.

[image]

[image]

I am able to Edit the Hostname successfully as shown below.

[image]

[image]

***My Role:***

[image]

[image]

- Once try to login into another browser/ Incognito Window, to avoid cache related issues.

Answer (score 0):

The binding configuration can be changed only on stage 1 of deployment process if you dont change anything if will use default setting and add binding checked box will be disable.

So as highlighted in red use Stage 1 to change binding and pool setting
[As i mentioned in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcXvf.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just speculating here: They wrote the code to auto-generate the binding during setup - easy. Now you want to rename that? File renaming, merging edits with your edits... Just disable renaming!